# Handling Unhandled event loop exception from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I'm doing an sms android app and it was working fine till now but now when I run the app, it is unable to receive a sms, it is immediately crashing when the sms is received and I'm getting errors from my Manifest.xml such as Malformed manifest and Unhandled event loop exeption in Error Log!

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aline.memoir.rcvsms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="aline.memoir.rcvsms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        !-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

         <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
               </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like one of those problems where you just need to do a "clean build" and everything will be OK again.

Comment: thx David but can u plz tell me how to do a "clean build" bcz I have started a new project with the same codes but now the app is not crashing, I can send but not receive!

Comment: Using your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio, whatever) you should be able to find an item in the "build" menu called "Clean" or "rebuild" or something like this. You probably have some old junk that isn't getting properly rebuilt. If you are having another problem with your app you should probably ask a new question.